# How to get only last bracket from multiple arrays? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a few arrays and I have to choose only what is in the last bracket. How to do it?

For example my some arrays always be similar, but be different:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)
)
Array
(
    [0] => BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 22 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R,W)
)
```

And i want get result from that like:

```
(F)
(R)
(R,W)
```

I must use substr or what?
Regards

Comment: You could use a regex. `\([^)]+$` If you've tried something you should add that so we can help with what your current issue is.

Comment: Need `\([^)]+\)$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can go

```
$arr = array(
        '3 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)',
        'BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R)',
        '22 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R,W)'
    );
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $lastElement = array_filter(explode('(',explode(':',$v)[1]));
    $newArr[] = '('.$lastElement[count($lastElement)];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
 [0] => (F)
 [1] => (R)
 [2] => (R,W)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with `preg_filter`

```
$arr = array(
    '3 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)',
    'BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R)',
    '22 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R,W)'
);

print_r(preg_filter('/^.+(\([^)]+\))$/', '\1', $arr));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => (F)
    [1] => (R)
    [2] => (R,W)
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be80157e9b2b28e19ccff4349f5668e09b01f3a1)

The Regex

- `^` - match start of string
- `.+` - match anything one or more "greedy"
- `(...)` - First Capture group

  - `\(` the `(` literally
  - `[^)]+` match anything "not" `)`
  - `\)` the `)` literally
- `$` - match end of string.

So what this does is replace everything in each array item that is not in the capture group with `\1` - the first capture group.  Which should match everything from the start of the last `(` to the end of that "set" `)`. Basically what we want is only that "stuff" the last parentheses set, which is good, because that's what the above code does (oddly enough, it's like someone set it just the way we need it ... lol).

This should also remove anything from the array that does not match that pattern.  For example:

```
$arr = array(
    '3 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)',
    'BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R)',
    '22 BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(R,W)',
    'foo' //--- foo will not appear in the results, because it does not end with (...)
);
```

Hope it helps!

> **preg_filter()** is identical to **preg_replace()** except it only returns the (possibly transformed) subjects where there was a match. For details about how this function works, read the **preg_replace()** documentation. 
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php

***PS** I gave the above example as it highlights the difference between `preg_replace()` and `preg_filter()` (mentioned above).  You could do the same with just `preg_replace()` if you are sure there will always be a match in each item.